# Convergence of product of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let say we have a sequence of functions $(f_ng)$ in $L^2[a,b]$, where $g$ is in $L^2[a,b]$, that converges to some function $h\in L^2[a,b]$.

i.e. $f_ng\to h$ in $L^2$ as $n\to\infty$.

($f_ng$ denotes product $f_n(x)g(x)$.)

1) Can we assume that $h$ is of the form $fg$ for some $f\in L^2[a,b]$?

2) Can we assume that $f_n$ converges to some $f$ in $L^2[a,b]$?

Update: Let's assume $g>0$, and $f_n$ is in $L^2[a,b]$.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $g$ and $f_n g$ are in $L^2[a;b]$ but $f_n$ doesn't have to be in $L^2([a;b])$, except if $|g(x)|> \epsilon$ for every $x \in [a;b]$

Comment: @user1952009 if $f_n$ is in $L^2$ does it work? (I added update to the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1): Let $g(a)=1.$ Let $g(x)=x-a$ for $x\in (a,b]. $ Let $a_n=a+2^{-n}(b-a).$ Let $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\in [a,a_n].$ Let $f_n(x)=1/g(x)$ for $x\in (a_n,b].$

Then $\int^b_a|f_ng-1|^2 dx=a_n-a=2^{-n}(b-a).$ So $f_ng$ converges in $L^2[a,b]$ to the constant function $h=1.$

But there is no $f\in L^2[a,b]$ such that $1=fg.$

For 2):Observe that $\|f_n\|\to \infty$  as $n\to \infty$ so $f_n$ does not converge to any $f\in L^2[a,b].$